# SampleMessageDialog in material design WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, material-design, material-ui

Hey all I am trying to figure out how to call the SampleMessageDialog in my own app.

So far this is the code i have for a button on my form that should open the message box:

```
Private Async Sub BrowseButton_Copy_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles BrowseButton_Copy.Click
    msgBoxPop.showPop()
End Sub
```

And this is the **showPop**:

```
Imports MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf
Imports newRegisterProg.MaterialDesignColors.WpfExample.Domain

Public Class msgBoxPop
    Public Shared Async Sub showPop()
        Dim sampleMessageDialog = New SampleMessageDialog()

        With sampleMessageDialog
            .Message.Text = "TEST!"
        End With

        Await DialogHost.Show(sampleMessageDialog, "RootDialog")
    End Sub
End Class
```

And finally this is the usercontrol:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MaterialDesignColors.WpfExample.Domain.SampleMessageDialog"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             x:Name="messagePOP"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             MaxWidth="400">
    <Grid Margin="16">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Message" 
                   Margin="0 6 0 0"
                   FontSize="18" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" 
                IsDefault="True" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                Margin="16 16 16 0"
                Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.CloseDialogCommand}">
            ACCEPT
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Currently when I click the button it gives an error of:

> Additional information: No loaded DialogHost instances.

on line:

```
Await DialogHost.Show(sampleMessageDialog, "RootDialog")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have a DialogHost in the XAML of the application anywhere?

A good place for it is right at the root, inside the window and containing the rest of your application:

```
<Window ....>
    <materialDesign:DialogHost>
        ...your app
    </<materialDesign:DialogHost>
</Window>
```

Comment: Sure. Are you adding your app content in code now? I don't know VB specific syntax, but before you add your app to the Content of Window, add a DialogHost and add said app to the Content of the DialogHost. DialogHost extends ContentControl, so just use it like that standard control.